# What is the meaning of "起風"?

Tags: meaning

This is one line of the song lyrics:

這個起風的季節說了再見。

When I look up the Chinese dictionary it say the meaning is 颳風 guāfēng means to be windy.

So the phrase 這個起風的季節說了再見。 means "This windy season say goodbye."

Or is there another meaning?

Answer (score 2):

“起風的季節” refers to Autumn. If you simply break it down and look at these two characters , 起 means “to start”; 風 can be directly translated as “wind.” Therefore you may conclude that 起風 means “the wind starts (to blow/blowing)”. The entire line can be understood as “The season, when the wind starts to blow, says goodbye.” Echoing to what hhyls2002 said, it is actually not the  season itself saying goodbye but the singer feeling that everything has come to an end as if all that has happened is now waving goodbye to him, in this season of changes, farewells and sorrow.

Answer (score 1):

China is on the eastern side of Asia. Here, when the winds begin to blow, it usually means that autumn is here. This is what people mean when they say 起风 in Chinese culture.

Many old Chinese stories and poems talk about autumn as a sad time. It's when things begin to wind down and decay. Autumn is also a time when people often say goodbye to their family and friends.

So, when Chinese people talk about 起风 or the wind starting, it can sometimes make them feel sad. This is because of the connection between wind, autumn, and saying goodbye.

There is a famous Chinese pop music talking about this：《起风了》

> 这一路上走走停停
> In this journey, I start and stop
>
> 顺着少年漂流的痕迹
> Following the tracks of a youngster's wandering
>
> 迈出车站的前一刻
> The moment before I leave the station
>
> 竟有些犹豫
> (I can't believe that) I am a little reluctant
>
> 不禁笑这近乡情怯
> I can't help but laugh about the complex feelings I have when nearing my home
>
> 仍无可避免
> It is unavoidable
>
> 而长野的天
> And the sky of Nagano
>
> 依旧那么暖
> is still so warm
>
> **风吹起了从前**
> **The wind stirs up the past**
>
> 从前初识这世间
> When I first got to know this world
>
> 万般流连
> All the lingering
>
> 看着天边似在眼前
> Watching the sky, which seemed close and within reach
>
> 也甘愿赴汤蹈火去走它一遍
> and I was willing to travel through it no matter how hard the ordeal
>
> 如今走过这世间
> Today, having walked throughout this world
>
> 万般流连
> all the lingering
>
> 翻过岁月不同侧脸
> turning the pages of time, having seen profiles of different faces
>
> 措不及防闯入你的笑颜
> Without any warning, barging in to your smiling face
>
> 我曾难自拔于世界之大
> I used to be obsessed with how big the world was
>
> 也沉溺于其中梦话
> And I used to wallow in its sleep talk
>
> 不得真假不做挣扎不惧笑话
> There was no way to know the truth, not struggling, not afraid to be laughed at
>
> 我曾将青春翻涌成她
> I had tumbled my youth into her
>
> 也曾指尖弹出盛夏
> I had also plucked my strings into the height of summer
>
> 心之所动且就随缘去吧
> If it moves your heart, then let cosmic connection take you there
>
> 逆着光行走任风吹雨打
> Walking against the light, letting the elements hit me
>
> 短短的路走走停停
> A short road, starting and stopping
>
> 也有了几分的距离
> There is a bit of distance
>
> 不知抚摸的是故事
> I don't know if what I caress is a story
>
> 还是段心情
> or a session of a mood
>
> 也许期待的不过是
> Maybe what I expect is just
>
> 与时间为敌
> to rise up against time
>
> 再次看到你
> To see you again
>
> 微凉晨光里
> in the chilly morning light
>
> 笑的很甜蜜
> Smiling happily
>
> 从前初识这世间
> When I first got to know this world
>
> 万般流连
> All the lingering
>
> 看着天边似在眼前
> Watching the sky, which seemed close and within reach
>
> 也甘愿赴汤蹈火去走它一遍
> and I was willing to travel through it no matter how hard the ordeal
>
> 如今走过这世间
> Today, having walked throughout this world
>
> 万般流连
> all the lingering
>
> 翻过岁月不同侧脸
> turning the pages of time, having seen profiles of different faces
>
> 措不及防闯入你的笑颜
> Without any warning, barging in to your smiling face
>
> 我曾难自拔于世界之大
> I used to be obsessed with how big the world was
>
> 也沉溺于其中梦话
> And I used to wallow in its sleep talk
>
> 不得真假不做挣扎不惧笑话
> There was no way to know the truth, not struggling, not afraid to be laughed at
>
> 我曾将青春翻涌成她
> I had tumbled my youth into her
>
> 也曾指尖弹出盛夏
> I had also plucked my strings into the height of summer
>
> 心之所动且就随缘去吧
> If it moves your heart, then let cosmic connection take you there
>
> **晚风吹起你鬓间的白发**
> **The night wind makes the hair on your temples dance**
>
> 抚平回忆留下的疤
> Healing the scar that memories left behind
>
> 你的眼中
> In your eyes
>
> 明暗交杂
> darkness and light mix
>
> 一笑生花
> A smile of yours blossoms like a flower
>
> 暮色遮住你蹒跚的步伐
> The slight dusk darkness hides your staggering gait
>
> 走进床头藏起的画
> Walking into the painting that's hidden in the headboard
>
> 画中的你低着头说话
> In the painting, you have your head hung, talking
>
> 我仍感叹于世界之大
> I still marvel at how big the world is
>
> 也沉醉于儿时情话
> And I also revel in les mots d'amour of my childhood
>
> 不剩真假不做挣扎无谓笑话
> There is no such thing as "right or wrong" left, not struggling, whether or not I get made fun of doesn't matter
>
> 我终将青春还给了她
> I have finally returned my youth to her
>
> 连同指尖弹出的盛夏
> along with the height of summer that I created with my plucking
>
> 心之所动就随风去了
> If it moves your heart, then let cosmic connection take you there
>
> 以爱之名你还愿意吗
> In the name of love, are you still willing?

Comment: "Autumn is also a time when people often say goodbye to their family and friends" In the olden days those living along the coasts travel by Junks and these needed strong winds to sail and so everyone had to wait for the strong Autumn winds. The cry, 起风了,(The winds are starting to blow) was a cry of joy and sadness. Joy for the sailors, sadness for the passengers, who are leaving either for home or for laborious work in far away lands like 南洋, Malaya, Singapore, Philippines, Indonesia and California called 金山 due to the gold rush there marking the Chinese diaspora which my ancestors took part.